# Rotating axis label in R

Tags: r, plot, rotation, label, axis

I would like help with rotating the axis label for the following plot. 
As is currently set up, the final label is not displayed because of limited space. I understand text, srt codes are used for this purpose but have not been able to rotate the labels that are currently shown (new numbers instead emerged IN the graph itself):

```
Xmin=0-2
Xmax=0+2
plot(x, y, type='n', xlab='x-axis',                               
    col.axis="grey", cex.axis=0.7, tck=-.02, xaxt="n")
x <- c(-2,2)
y <- c(-1,1)
plot(x, y, type='n', xlab='x-axis', col.axis="grey", cex.axis=0.7,       
tck=-.02, xaxt="n")
abline(a=-.6, b=-.2, lty=1, pch=15, lwd=1, col='black') 
abline(a=.03, b=.2, lty=5, pch=15, lwd=1, col='black')
axis(1, at=c(-2, -1, 1.9, 2), labels=c("8.07", "8.976", "11.7",          
"11.9"), tck=.01, cex.axis=0.9, srt=45, col.ticks = "grey")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding las=2

```
axis(1, at=c(-2, -1, 1.9, 2), labels=c("8.07", "8.976", "11.7",          
               "11.9"), tck=.01, cex.axis=0.9, srt=45, col.ticks = "grey", las=2)
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! This is an entirely different question but the limited space between the last 2 points seems to require 1) increasing space 2) reducing font size or 3) perhaps another degree of rotation (45degrees?) Is there a most obvious solution to this issue?

Comment: My first reaction is that rotation wouldn't seem to get you more white space IMO. You could maybe fudge something in with 'text(1,1,"hlp", srt=90)', but you'll need to tweak the 1's to get the placement to what you want.

Comment: Does srt work in `axis()`? I don't see it works on my test. So `text()` has to be used instead?